# What is best way of finding array element intersection on rxjs

Tags: arrays, rxjs, intersection

I know There is `includes` *Operator* on *JavaScript* *Array*.

So, Finding common elements from two other Arrays is no Problem. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885569/11455650)

Then, What is best way for this on `rxjs`?

```js
const obs1$ = from(["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]);
const obs2$ = from(["bar", "garply", "fred", "foo"];

// const commonIntersection$ = functions or operators...
// result must be ["foo", "bar"]
```

I think there are two way for implementing this.

Which one is computationally efficient and How can I implement this with `rxjs` *Operator*?

1. `merge` Two Array and emit only Second value (ignore First Value)
2. `filter` each of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want a running intersection from each emission?  If so you can either use the *scan* operator, or roll your own specific *intersection* operator.

The *scan* operator is like the *reduce* method on arrays.  In this case, for each element (which is an array of strings) the intersection is returned.  Each following emission will work on that last result.

```
merge(from([["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"], ["bar", "garply", "fred", "foo"]])).pipe(
  map(x => x),
  scan((acc, cur) => {
    return (!acc) 
      ? next
      : acc.filter(x => cur.includes(x));
  }, undefined as string[] | undefined),
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

A custom operator will look cleaner, so if you need it multiple times, then go for it!  As you can see the logic below is essentially the same as the **scan** version.  It keeps track of the running intersection state in the **acc** variable, and the **cur**rent array is used to update it.

```
merge(from([["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"], ["bar", "garply", "fred", "foo"]])).pipe(
  map(x => x),
  intersection(),
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

/*...*/

function intersection<T>(): OperatorFunction<T[], T[]> {
  return (observable: Observable<T[]>) => {
    return new Observable<T[]>((subscriber) => {
      let acc: T[] | undefined; // keeps track of the state.
      const subscription = observable.subscribe({
        next: (cur) => {
          acc = (!acc) 
            ? cur
            : acc.filter(x => cur.includes(x));
          subscriber.next(acc);
        },
        error: (err) => subscriber.error(err),
        complete: () => subscriber.complete(),
      });
      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    })
  }
}
```

If you only want the last result then change the **scan** operator to **reduce**, or only emit the value of **acc** in the complete callback of the inner subscription in the operator version.

Comment: It emits also first array. so can I use `skip(1)` for only intersection result? It seems wasting computing resource though...

Comment: For the operator version you can just not `next(acc)` the first result.  If you know you're only going to have two emissions, or want to wait for the last emission, you can use the reduce operator.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { forkJoin, from } from 'rxjs';
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { intersection } from 'lodash';

const obs1$ = from(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']);
const obs2$ = from(['bar', 'garply', 'fred', 'foo']);

forkJoin([obs1$.pipe(toArray()), obs2$.pipe(toArray())]).subscribe(
  ([arr1, arr2]) => console.log(intersection(arr1, arr2))
);
```

Try here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6jdyzy?file=index.ts

Comment: No `rxjs Operator` for *lodash* `intersection`- like? I just want to build without `lodash`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not `rxjs` used codes but used *JavaScript* Native Array methods (*filter*, *includes*).

It seems faster than `rxjs` operator.

```js
const intersectionArray = combineLatest({
  firstArray: [["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]],
  secondArray: [["bar", "garply", "fred", "foo"]],
}).pipe(
  map((x) => x.firstArray.filter((value) => x.secondArray.includes(value)))
);

intersectionArray.subscribe(console.log);
```